# How do I check the latest SVN logs, without doing svn update?

Tags: svn

Let's say I haven't `svn update` in a while.  However, before I want to do a svn update, I want to see what has been changed.

How can I do that?

Comment: `svn log FILE ` should help........

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
svn status --show-updates
```

Learn more about the 'status' command in [the SVN Redbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re26.html)

Comment: +1, this is the exact purpose of this command / flag. Short form being `svn st -u`

Answer (score 5):

`svn log -r BASE:HEAD` will display the log between the current BASE and the HEAD of the repository.

Answer (score 1):

For sake of other users ( or even OP if they are using TortoiseSVN), in order to achieve the same with TortoiseSVN:

Right-click on your working copy folder, choose "Check for modifications". In that dialog, click on the button "Check repository".

( in the background, this does use the `svn st -u` svn command like @Gareth Western mentions )

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `show history`. It logs all the actions and updates done in the file or project.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
   svn log --limit 1 URL
```